# javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not find service named

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm getting the following error while calling a `SOAP` webservice

> `Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not find service named {http://services.yell.es}LogonSrv in wsdl http://piquio.intrayell.com:10180/docmanagementapp-5.1/services/LogonSrv?wsdl`

My `WSDL` file is:
http://piquio.intrayell.com:10180/docmanagementapp-5.1/services/LogonSrv?wsdl

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The namespace specified in the client (`http://services.yell.es`) does not match the one in the wsdl file.

Answer (score 0):

The `targetNamespace` value in your `LogonSrv.java` should get from http://piquio.intrayell.com:10180/docmanagementapp-5.1/services/LogonSrv?wsdl

In my situation, I open my wsdl url in chrome, then find `targetNamespace` attribute at the begining, set it into my `xxxSrv.java`.

Apart from this, I aslo have another file associate to something `HttpPort`, the `name` in it, I copy from the same wsdl url.